# std::is_constructible returns inconsistent value for private constructor

Tags: c++, type-traits

What are the rules by which `std::is_constructible` handles private constructors? Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class {
private:
    Class() { }
};

template <typename T>
class Test {
public:
    static void test() {
        std::cout
            //<< std::is_constructible<Class>::value
            << std::is_constructible<T>::value
            << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<Class>::test();
}
```

This prints `0` ([ideone](https://ideone.com/zA277R)), i.e., `T` is not default constructible.

Uncommenting the commented line, it prints `11` ([ideone](https://ideone.com/pfP31F)), so `T` suddently became default constructible.

I could find reasoning to support both results, but I don't understand how including the commented line changes the result of the second. Is this somehow invoking UB? Is this a compiler bug? Or is `std::is_constructible` really that inconsistent?

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug, [clang 9 prints `00`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WWfVTFu323Hq5gt9)

Comment: `is_constructible<T>` should be `false` for inaccessible constructors. So it seems like a bug that an implementation would provide `true`. I believe the correct output should be `00` with the line uncommented.

Comment: Another strange think I notice when compiling at my machine with c++17 g++9.2.1 / g++-10.0 and replacing std::is_constructible<...>::value with is_constructible_v<...>, is that the [result changes to 00](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rGNbJvYZJEJISSSA)

Comment: @mutableVoid Indeed - and it seems that the `::value` version is capable of changing the output of those coming before it too: https://godbolt.org/z/zCy5xU Uncomment the commented line and all becomes 1:s in gcc.

Comment: Another way to fix it: https://godbolt.org/z/EKaP3r so basically this is some kind evaluation order bug.

Comment: So basically  the issue occurs in g++ when is_constructible is evoked first from a static, templated structure or function and the constructor is private, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/-VELfA) is a slightly more minimal example.

Comment: @mutableVoid You don't even need to instantiate the function template for it to become true. In this example, it returns `false` but if the function template is uncommented, it suddenly returns `true`:
https://godbolt.org/z/zqxdk2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_constructible` should return `false` in this scenario because the  constructor is not accessible.

As pointed out underneath the question, the behavior described in the question is caused by a bug in GCC / libstdc++. The bug is [reported here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94003), and, according to the Bugzilla,  related to if not caused by  an [access control bug for classes in template functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437) that has been unresolved for quite a while. The relationship between the two bugs is taken from Jonathan Wakely's Bugzilla comment who seems to have detected the connection between the two bugs first.

This is also implied by the fact that the behavior of this scenario in GCC becomes correct when deleting the constructor instead of making it private:

```cpp
class Class {
    Class() = delete;
};
```

which prints out `0` and `00` respectively. 
This is the correct output (which `clang` correctly reports  in the scenario with a private constructor aswell).

This could explain the [observed change of behavior](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94003) when commenting in the line, because inside the function in the  *templated* struct, access checking doesn't work and reports that the constructor is accessible when it's not. When the trait is checked again in the next line or possibly at a completely different location (as is the case [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zqxdk2)), it has already been instantiated, and thus yields the wrong answer.